# Fatfree DB Connection using FreeTDS

Tags: sql-server, database, connection

I am using the Fatfree Framework and trying to connect to a MSSQL-Server using FreeTDS.
The FreeTDS is allready used by a another website so the connection FreeTDS/MSSQL is working correctly.

Please, can someone help me with the DB-Connection using fatfree?

This are the infos a got from the working page (FreeTDS-Parameters odbc.ini):

```
define('SQL_DATABASE', 'TEST_DB');
define('SQL_HOST', 'TEST_HOST');
define('SQL_USER', 'TEST_USER');
define('SQL_PASSWORD', 'TEST_PASS');
```

How shoud the connection-string should look for freetds?

```
$db = new DB\SQL('dblib:SERVERNAME='.SQL_HOST.';Database='.SQL_DATABASE,SQL_USER,SQL_PASSWORD);
```

Returns an error: could not find driver

freetds.conf

```
[global]
dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
debug level = 10

[TEST_HOST]
host = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
client charset = ISO-8859-1
```

I enabled the FreeTDS-Logging.
Cant find "TEST_HOST" in the logfile, just a lot from the working page.

It look like fatfree is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:

```
dblib.c:4945:dberrhandle(0x7fa187a5e1e0)
dblib.c:4964:dbmsghandle(0x7fa187a5e330)
dblib.c:761:dbsetlname(0x7fa19b6b65f0, TEST_USER, 2)
dblib.c:761:dbsetlname(0x7fa19b6b65f0, TEST_PASS, 3)
dblib.c:761:dbsetlname(0x7fa19b6b65f0, PHP freetds, 5)
dblib.c:1146:dbopen(0x7fa19b6b65f0, 127.0.0.1, [sybase])
dblib.c:273:dblib_get_tds_ctx(void)
config.c:185:Getting connection information for [127.0.0.1].
```

Found it couse of the TEST_USER and TEST_DB in the log.

Comment: Is that the same connection string you are using for the working site?

Comment: The working page dont use fatfree,   $mssql_connection = @mssql_connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASSWORD);

Comment: Can you post the relevant server config info from freetds.conf?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running this on? If you're using *nix, use dblib in your DSN in the connection string:

```
$db = new DB\SQL('dblib:host='.SQL_HOST.';dbname='.SQL_DATABASE,SQL_USER,SQL_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: new error: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)

Comment: That usually indicates a problem with your freetds.conf configuration or something else in the connection string (username, password). Double check those configuration settings.

Comment: i added the freetds.conf above. the define statements for host, db, user, pass are copy/pasted. i think it must be the connections string couse the other pages (mssql_connect) works perfekt. Why i cant use "mssql:..." => http://fatfreeframework.com/sql#Constructor

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Correct Connection String is:

```
$db = new DB\SQL('odbc:dsn='.SQL_HOST.';database='.SQL_DATABASE,SQL_USER,SQL_PASSWORD);
```